# good idiom for empty containers with std::all_of( ) and std:none_of( )?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl-algorithm

Both std::all_of( ) and std:none_of( ) return true for empty containers.

Aside from debating the conceptual aspect of this, can someone suggest an idiom that does not call for always checking if the container is empty AND checking for all_of or none_of?

This is bothersome in that using the same predicate in both algorithms on an empty container will indicate that the predicate is true for both ALL and NONE of the elements. So, your (empty) vector is all_of "odd", all_of "even", none_of "odd" and none_of "even".

On a more practical level I am thinking in terms of checking a collection of items for a status, like are any "ready for processing", and expect an empty collection to correspond to "NO, there are no elements ready to be processed".  I know I can check if it is empty separately but I am looking for other possibilities.

Comment: What's the problem? Even if you would have `if (all_of(range, ready_for_processing)) for (auto& e : range) process(e);` that's fine.

Comment: if none_of yields true for a "ready for processing" predicate on an empty container, that seems like the correct answer to me.

Comment: `all_of` is "for all x in S, P(x)".  `none_of` is "for all x in S, !P(x)".  `any_of` is "there exists x in S, P(x)".  `all_of` and `none_of` are not negations of each other -- `!`"for all x in S, P(x)" is "there exists x, !P(x)" (aka `any_of(...,!P)`), and `!none_of(...)` is `any_of(...)`.

Comment: @Yakk Huh?  I am asking about the case of an empty set. For a predicate such as "isEven"... for the empty set all_of("isEven") returns TRUE.   Furthermore, while I KNOW all_of and none_of are not inverses the issue is that they are both true for the EMPTY set.  (Johannes and ipc, thanks for your input).

Comment: I am about to mark this answered but I'd like to see input from others.  It is interesting that while I confirmed this oddity of *all_of* in the C++11 spec, the Microsoft page on this seems to address the "problem" and says "Returns true if the condition is detected at each element in the indicated range, and _false if the condition is not detected at least one time_."  I agree with that.  Again, if you have a collection of "shapes" which happens to be empty, and you ask "are they all squares" the only accurate Boolean response would have to be *false*.

Comment: @Arbalest "for all x in {}, isEven(x)" is true. This is known as vacuous satisfaction -- "for all x in {}, P(x)" is true for every predicate P. Thus `all_of` returns true.  This is not an oddity in the C++11 spec: it is an oddity in logic.  "Are all elements of this empty set squares" is true, and that is the only accurate Boolean response. "Is there an element of this empty set that is a square" would be false. "Are all elements of this empty set non-squares" would be true. Your confusion is common, but your conclusion is wrong.

Comment: _This is not an oddity in the C++11 spec: it is an oddity in logic._  Thanks, that made my day :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own wrapper and use that to modify the result if the container is empty:

```
// in your namespace, not std:
template< class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate >
bool none_of( InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p )
{
  return first != last && std::none_of( first, last, p );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is along the lines of what I was asking for.

Answer (score 16):

> On a more practical level I am thinking in terms of checking a collection of items for a status, like are any "ready for processing", and expect an empty collection to correspond to "NO, there are no elements ready to be processed".

That's why `std::any_of()` does return `false` for an empty collection.

If the question would be "Are *all* items finished processing?", then the expected answer would by "Yes, everything is finished." if there weren't any items to be processed in the first place (That's the `std::all_of()` case).

Similarily, the question "Did no errors occur during processing?" would be answered "Yes, there were no errors." for an empty list (no work -> no errors). This is what `std::none_of()` checks for.